# Making sessions for login with all different redirect page

Tags: php, mysql

)
I'm working on a login system that has 3 users(Admin, Teacher and Student) all of these users will have their own functions and interface. I would like to have **one** login for all these users together if this is possible i'm not sure.

Im my database there is a row Role('Admin','Teacher','Student') i want the login direct based on the "role" so the admin will be redirect to the admin homepage, the teacher to the teacher homepage and the student to the student homepage. The admin pages can only be viewed by the admin the teacher pages by the teacher and the student pages only by the students. You probably get what I mean.

**Question::
How can i make the login so that it will check if it is a admin/teacher/student? and when they are logged in how can i make the specific homepage for that user vieuwable only by that type of user?**

```
<?php
session_start();
$mysqli=new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "", "hws");
$role="";

$username=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if($query=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT `role` FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?"))
{
    $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($role);
    $query->fetch();
}
else
{
    echo "Errors in the Query. ".$mysqli->error;
    die();
}

    if($role!="")
    {
        $_SESSION['ingelogt']=$username;
        $_SESSION['user_role']=$role;
        $location="$role.php"; // If role is admin this will be admin.php, if student this will be student.php and more.
        header("location: $location"); // Redirect to the respective pages.
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid password, username combination";
    }

?>
```

and for the userpage a example

```
<?php
session_start()
if(!isset($_SESSION['ingelogt']))
{
    header("location: index.php"); // The user is not logged in. Redirect him to the login page.
}

$page_role="leerling"; // This must be admin for admin.php and student for student.php and similar

$role=$_SESSION['user_role'];

if($role!=$page_role) // If student come to admin page by mistake or admin to student and similar
{
    echo "You are not supposed to be here.";
    die();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="siteContainer">
            <div class="navLeft">
                <a href="overzicht.php">
                    <img src="../../img/logo.png" alt="HWSysteem" class="mainLogo">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is your question and where you are struggling?

Comment: sorry totaly forgot to put in in there!
Post has been edited.

Comment: Have you been able to store the username and password in your database?

Comment: Yes, im able to login with it. the current login works fine but just like any other will with a general user. so not the 3 users i ment before.

Comment: Okay based on the code you posted on your question, I infer you save the password barely in the database. This is really need to be changed for security reasons. You must hash your passwords and save the hashed value in the database. I will post the logic as a answer here. Read about password hashing here, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: I'll go and check it out. And i'm aware of that i have to hash the passwords. since the project wont be online for a long time i was working on the other side of the login first. Ill go try to hash the password and save it hashed first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am more comfortable with prepared statements, I have used it here. This is a simple logic example for your requirement.

```
<?php
session_start();
$mysqli=new MySQLi("localhost", "USER_NAME_HERE", "PASSWORD_HERE");
$role="";

$username=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if($query=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT `role` FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?"))
{
    $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($role);
    $query->fetch();
}
else
{
    echo "Errors in the Query. ".$mysqli->error;
    die();
}

    if($role!="")
    {
        $_SESSION['ingelogt']=$username;
        $_SESSION['user_role']=$role;
        $location="$role.php"; // If role is admin this will be admin.php, if student this will be student.php and more.
        header("location: $location"); // Redirect to the respective pages.
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid password, username combination";
    }

?>

And in your admin.php, student.php

<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['ingelogt']))
{
    header("location: login.php"); // The user is not logged in. Redirect him to the login page.
}

$page_role="admin"; // This must be admin for admin.php and student for student.php and similar

$role=$_SESSION['user_role'];

if($role!=$page_role) // If student come to admin page by mistake or admin to student and similar
{
    echo "You are not supposed to be here.";
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-)
So this is basically the new login script? or is this next to the login script the check role script?

Comment: This is the script which will check for the login. If login is success it will get the role.

Comment: I really need to learn more about this stuff :P
So my own login script is in the past? this script checks the role and after that it loggs in?

Comment: Yes, from the database, it gets the role and store in the variable `$role`. And based on the value stored in this variable you are making the redirect.

Comment: So in my previous script i declared the username and password in $username $password to know that the data that has been filled in the input type is the username or the password. don't i have to do that here?

Comment: `$username = $_POST['username']` is what I did in the 5th line. The way I did will filter any unwanted quotes and special characters from the user input. That will reduce the SQL Injection attack probability.

Comment: Yay, i understand it! now i've analysed the code i totally understand it! It is a very compact code! i'm gonna study it some more so i can write it myself! One more question. about the password hash i have been told to use md5. is this a good option?

Comment: No md5 is outdated and proved to be crack-able. You can use PHP's built-in  function password hash. I have given you the link in the comments under the question. Only limitation is your PHP version must be at least 5.5. If your PHP version is lesser than 5.5 go for PBKDF2. Search in Google.

Comment: Okay ill go and check it out.

Comment: If your PHP version is >=5.5 you can use the PHP built-in function. It will be really simple and easy process,

Comment: Thanks, do you also have any idea how i can make the pages viewable for the users that have the rights to visit these?

Comment: The code below this line **And in your admin.php, student.php** will do that. If the user's role and page role is not same, the page will print the error and stop. If not the page will be displayed fully.

Comment: nvm i found it. but somehow it doesnt works at all. all the pages are still visitable without being logged in or being logged in as a different user.? :'(

Comment: Have you included `session_start()` in the pages?

Comment: Ok, somehow i got it working but now its telling me there is something wrong with the first if isset? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\HWS\admin.php on line 3

Comment: Edit your question and post that code as separate so that I can have a look.

Comment: You need to keep a semi-colon after `session_start()`. The correct syntax is `session_start();` :D